# Calling a third party service on a client

Tags: ros, rospy, service, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to write a service client in python to `enable_motors` of `hector_quadrotor`. I would like to turn on engine on my code instead of doing that by invoking the provided service

In [Writing the Client Node](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29) tutorial it is used `rospy.ServiceProxy`. However, this method needs the service type which is implemented on the server side, which I don't have access.

My doubt is: How can I call a service that was defined by a third part?
It is similar to that question, I'm coding in `python` not in C++ though:
https://answers.ros.org/question/201617/how-to-call-a-service-inside-a-node/

EDIT:
In my case it gets:

```
       motors_on = rospy.ServiceProxy('enable_motors', hector_uav_msgs/EnableMotors)
       TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'module' and 'type'
```

and results on the error above

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280417/calling-a-third-party-service-on-a-client/) by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bit of a guess, but:

> However, this method needs a callback function which is implemented on the server side, which I don't have access.

Are you referring to this line in the [Writing the Client Node](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingServiceClient.Writing_the_Client_Node) section:

> ```
> add_two_ints = rospy.ServiceProxy('add_two_ints', AddTwoInts)
> ```

and then specifically `AddTwoInts`?

That is not a callback method, but the type of the service.

---

Edit:

> However the issue stands: How call I call the the service, once I don't have access to server side of code?

I don't really understand your question. Is the tutorial not clear?

You create a `ServiceProxy` instance. This instance is a *callable* by itself, so once bound, you can invoke the service by doing something like:

```
result = add_two_ints(1, 2)
```

See also [wiki/rospy/Overview/Services - Service proxies](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Services#Service_proxies) on the wiki, which might be clearer than the tutorial.

If this still doesn't help you, then you'll have to explain more precisely what it is you don't understand.

---

Edit2: are you actually wondering how to get access to the *type definitions* for the remote service? If that is the case, you'll have to make sure to `import` the correct class from the ROS package that defines the service files.

For the `hector_quadrotor` collection of packages, that is probably `hector_uav_msgs`, so something like the following should work (after having declared a proper `run_depend` on the package):

```
from hector_uav_msgs.srv import EnableMotors
```

and then the `ServiceProxy` instance should be created like so:

```
motors_on = rospy.ServiceProxy('enable_motors', EnableMotors)
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) on 2018-01-22**:
Yes, I saw it now. I edited my question. However the issue stands: How call I call the the service, once I don't have access to server side of code?

**Comment by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) on 2018-01-22**:
OK. My issue is access service type

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-22**:
In that case see Edit2.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-22**:
Btw: I get the feeling you don't have much experience with Python. That is fine, but I would suggest you first find some good tutorials or a book about Python itself, and *then* start looking at `rospy`. Trying to learn all of this at the same time is going to be quite involved.